Spring boot 3 Internationalization with variants
I would like to have internationalization for a given language with different variants.
My case is to display for the same language, different messages according to if the user is a teacher or a student.
So I have tried messages files like :
messages_fr_FR_ST.properties
messages_fr_FR_TE.properties
messages_fr_FR_st.properties
messages_fr_FR_te.properties
messages_fr_FR_student.properties
messages_fr_FR_teacher.properties
messages_fr__st.properties
messages_fr__te.properties

but they seem not detected, while messages_fr.properties is.
I made the locale like that :
Locale(Locale.FRANCE.language, Locale.FRANCE.country, "st")
Locale(Locale.FRANCE.language, Locale.FRANCE.country, "ST")
Locale(Locale.FRANCE.language, Locale.FRANCE.country, "student")
...

I digged a bit inside the MessageSource of Spring. In that doc I found the function calculateFilenamesForLocale saying following the rules defined by Locale.toString()
So I don't understand where the problem comes from. Any idea ? Thank you.

Which MessageSource are you using? The default configured by Spring Boot, are you overriding it? What does your configuration look like? How is the Locale being changed? The default is to use the Accept-Header one, so if that still is in place it will only resolve the default Locale.

Hello @M.Deinum, I'm not using the http headers and the local of the request context. Instead I call the message source with the locale (that I built myself) as argument : messageSource.getMessage(code,args,Locale(Locale.FRANCE.language, Locale.FRANCE.country, "ST")
)
The only config I have changed from the default MessageSource is fallback-to-system-locale: false.

Found it. Surprisingly, spring requires a base file from which we can add variants. So this kind of setup works :
messages.properties <<<< required I guess for sprint to understand the basename and the fallback of any not found locale.
messages_fr_FR_student.properties <<< can be called with messageSource.getMessage(code,args,Locale(Locale.FRANCE.language, Locale.FRANCE.country, "student") )
messages_fr__te.properties <<< messageSource.getMessage(code,args,Locale(Locale.FRANCE.language, "", "te") )

